# Separable Least squares - is there a notion of conjugate directions?

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization

I have a general question.
Suppose I have the following to optimize
$$\|Y-A(\mathbf{x})B(\mathbf{y})\|^2$$
where $Y$ is a vector, $A(\mathbf{x})$ is a matrix that depends on a vector $\mathbf{x}$ in a linear way, i.e., the elements of $A(\mathbf{x})$ are those in $\mathbf{x}$, but the x-values show up "here and there" in $A(\mathbf{x})$. The same holds for $B(\mathbf{y})$. "Here and there" is a in fact a very complicated pattern, and will not help much.
In my problem, I'm only interested in the value of $\mathbf{x}$ that minimizes the cost, but both $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are to be optimized over.
To make the problem feasible, one element of $\mathbf{x}$ is frozen to an arbitrary value, say 1.

Given a starting position $\mathbf{x}_0$, I can solve for the optimal $\mathbf{y}$ by just applying the Moore-Penrose inverse. Then, with that $\mathbf{y}$, I can update my $\mathbf{x}$ with the Moore-Penrose inverse, and so on and on.

An alternative would to define the optimal $B(\mathbf{y})$ as a function of $\mathbf{x}$, denote this by $B^{\mathrm{opt}}(\mathbf{x})$ and then solve
$$\|Y-A(\mathbf{x})B^{\mathrm{opt}}(\mathbf{x})\|^2.$$

In the latter case, I can solve this for example with a gradient method, or with a conjugate gradient method.

Here is now my questions:

1. Is there a relation between a gradient method and the iterative least squares method above?
2. In the gradient method, I can speed up by doing a conjugate method. Is there any possibility to carry the "conjugate" framework over to the iterative method, so that I don't undo the improvements I did in iteration k-1 in iteration k?
3. Is there any other simple good method that is suitable for this type of problems?

This is just a small part of a paper I'm writing, so I am not so much interested in diving deep into this type of optimization problems, but I still need something that works and that shows that doesn't look to stupid…

Comment: Despite first appearances, the problem you have described is nonconvex (it can be cast as an equivalent bilinear matrix inequality). The method of alternating minimizations is not even guaranteed to converge to a stationary point, let alone the true optimal point for the problem.

Comment: You could also use the Newton method.